# Is it possible to track a call from a queue to where it ended up?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a script that is saving our Teams Direct Routing Call records to a database.
Direct calls seem easy to follow as they are only the one entry from what I can see.
This issue is I can see a call come into a queue but not where the call went to after.
I suppose its probably the same issue with if a direct call got transferred to someone else.

Is there a way to tie all linked entries together or are there just no additional entries after the initial one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest one i remember is that you may want to give a try by tracking a call through transfers using compliance bot. I remember [a related thread on this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/issues/212).

Comment: This looks promising, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Consider upvoting it and accepting it as answer. So it can be useful to others in the community as well :)